# How to prevent some of the unittest files from running

Tags: android, junit

I have few unit tests setup using juit in unittest1.java unittest2.java unittest3.java in android.

I want unittest1 and unittest2 not run when I am writing unittest3.java. Is there a way to do that. Googgling did not yield much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go inside your `unittest3.java` and click Ctrl+F11 for Run or F11 for Debug. This will run only tests inside current class.

Also, you can setup Run/Debug configurations manually. Assuming I have `MacTest.java` file with MacTest class inside:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Out of habit I have been running the unittest from the application panel.